# can't upload image using php

Tags: php, html

I'm having problems uploading an image to a server.

My form code is as below:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_image.php" method="POST">
<label for="file[]">Image 1: </label><input type="file" name="file[]" id="file[]" />
    <br / >
<label for="file[]">Image 2: </label><input type="file" name="file[]" id="file[]" />
<br / >
<input type="submit" value="Upload" /> </form>
```

My upload_image.php code is as below:

```
<?php
 move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["file"]["name"][0], "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"][0]);
 move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["file"]["name"][1], "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"][1]); ?>
```

When I try to upload images, nothing happens, and no image is uploaded to the server. Please help me find what went wrong with my script.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Why are you using `name` and `id` attributes like this `file[]`?

Comment: file[] means file array or file list

Comment: yes, it means for multiple file upload. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use 'tmp_name' in the first part.

```
<?php
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][0], "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"][0]);
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][1], "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"][1]); ?>
```

Comment: i had try the tmp_name, but still no luck. No images are beign uploaded.

Comment: Do you have write permission to the upload directory?

Comment: i had found the answer.

i changed the code as below:

    <?php 
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][0], "upload/" . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"][0])); 
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][1], "upload/" . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"][1])); 
    ?>

apparently it has to do with "tmp_name" and have to add in the basename function in order to upload images. Next step will have to do more validation on file type and file size.

Julian, thanks a lot for the help.